# Contacting patent owner?

Tags: search, inventor, owner, contact

I am interested in contacting the owner of this patent EP2120618B1 I found through a google patent search. How can I find owner/inventor information?

Comment: Thank you for your efforts in helping me answer this question. George White, I am not used to reading patents but you mentioned it is not in force anywhere but to me it looks active and has a PCT file associated with it. Does this not mean that it covers many countries and is active in the US?

Comment: Having PCT file doesn't mean the patent is active. The link George provided suggests that there aren't any countries where the patent is currently active. Whether a "Lapsed Patent" can be reactivated should be posed as a new question. If you do, I'd use the link George provided. George found no equivalent US patent so that likely means no patent exists in the US. In any case, you aren't going to get a legal opinion here. If you want that, I suggest asking an actual patent attorney for one.

Answer (score 1):

*Note - I do not think it is in force anywhere but you should study that closely if you are thinking about practicing it.*

If you go to the [google patents page for this patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/EP2120618B1/en?oq=%20EP2120618B1) you can click on getting the PDF.

On the face of the patent you will see -

[image]

It shows the owner, the inventor and the attorney/agent/representative who prosecuted it. You might get more information from clicking on the Espacent link to the patent and then clicking on the EP register. Or you may be able to go from the google patents page right to the EP Register. One tab within it shows all the back and forth between the EPO and the applicant and you may find other relevant contact information.

It is possible the initial owner has sold their rights to another entity since the patent has issued.

Importantly, you might look at this page in the EP register first.
https://register.epo.org/application?number=EP08719309&lng=en&tab=federated

It shows a long list of "not validated", "patent lapsed", and "patent not in force" for European countries. I do not think it was ever pursued in the U.S.

Comment: Good point checking patent status. I looks like the patent isn't active anywhere at this point. You may want to emphasize that.

Comment: It isn't directly answering the question but, I agree, it is most probably important to the OP.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts in helping me answer this question. I am not used to reading patents but you mentioned it is not in force anywhere but to me it looks active and has a PCT file associated with it. Does this not mean that it covers many countries and is active in the US?

Comment: A PCT application is one filing that acts as an application simultaneously in 140+ places. However, those applications die in a few months (~30months after priority filing) unless paperwork and money are submitted in a specific place to keep it alive their. This is the National phase data for the PCT application. It only shows it was entered into the national phase in Europe. https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2008107791  It is dead elsewhere. I provided a link the state of the EP situation which is filled with information about the lapsed status in many places.

Comment: I'm not saying 100% that it is not a valid patent anywhere whatsoever - I'm saying that it doesn't look like it is. Before taking too many steps in bringing a product to market It might make sense to have a freedom to operate search performed. And before contacting the owner it would be good to know if it was worth anything.